# Build C/C++ application in Eclipse using CDT plugin

Tags: c++

I am trying to build one C++ Application in Eclipse IDE,

I installed Eclipse IDE and then installed CDT plugin then now trying to build the application but every time facing a new issues, those are:

1. Nothing to be build for Project.
2. command line error D8037: cannot create temporary il files; clean temp directory of old il files.
3. ...\build\src\projet.dir\debug\project_manifest.rc(1):error Rc2135: file not found: project.dir\debug\project.exe.embed.manifest.

I got some of the solutions, I tried those solutions but those are not solved my issue,what I have done is:

For the first problem "Nothing to be build for Project",

1. Refreshing the project and  building it.
2. Eclipse IDE->Windows->Preferences->General->Workspacce->text file encoding->other-"UTF-8"

For the second problem:

1. opening the temporary files(Windows+R, %temp%) and deleting all the temp files, after trying to build the project, but no use.

I am not able to understand what is meaning of third error.

How to solve these issues?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What build system (CMake, Make, Ninja, Waf, Scons, ...) is used by your project? Can you show the definition of your build system?

Comment: I am using cMake for my project

Comment: Please show the relevant CMakeLists.txt files then, along with a list of the source files in your project.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response...

Comment: Please find the screenshots attached with my query,which shows cMakeLists.txt file and source file as well

Comment: You need additional plugins to use CMake within eclipse. CDT is not sufficient. A good solution is provided by the plugin [`cmake4eclipse`](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cmake4eclipse).

Comment: I have checked in help-help contents(Eclipse IDE) but I didn't found any results, could you please tell me how to install cmake plugin in Eclipse IDE or any link for installing cmake plugin..I am using Eclipse version Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a).

Comment: The developers of the plugin provide a description of how to install cmake4eclipse at this link: https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link but when I am trying with drag and drop method getting error "unable  to connect to repository"....and I don't have a option called  "Eclipse marketplace" in help section...any suggestions please.

Comment: Hi ...I installed the Eclipse markeplace and cMake4eclipse plugin also ..so could you tell me how to proceed next.

Comment: Good Morning all, waiting for your responses.